# In extjs4 how to set focus to newly added treeNode

Tags: extjs4, treepanel

i am working in extjs4. Ihave treeview with treeStore. i have functionality to add new nodes to tree. Its working correctly.newly added noded are getting appended correctly. But after adding this new node,i want to set focus to this newly created treeNode. So how to set focus to newly added node in extjs4?

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.tree.Panel` supports the [itemappend](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-itemappend) and [iteminsert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-iteminsert) events. You can listen for these events and use the selection model to focus on the node.

```
myTreeGrid.on('itemappend', function (parent, node) {
    this.getSelectionModel().select([node]);
}, myTreeGrid);
```